# PHP implode alternative inside mysql queries

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I need some alternative of implode for mysql queries.After research found concat functions.

Question is, can I concat by whitespace like that CONCAT_WS(' ',sender.fname, sender.mname, sender.lname) AS sender_name ? is there any chance that it will give error if one of values is null?

Here is my query.

```
SELECT message.id, message.from_id, message.to_id, message.subject, 
                    message.date, message.deleted, message.read, 
                    CONCAT_WS(' ',sender.fname, sender.mname, sender.lname) AS sender_name, 
                    CONCAT_WS(' ',recipient.fname, recipient.mname, recipient.lname) AS recipient_name,  
                    FROM msghistory AS message 
                    LEFT JOIN users AS sender ON sender.id=message.from_id, 
                    LEFT JOIN users AS recipient ON recipient.id=message.to_id 
                    GROUP BY message.id DESC
```

One more question, in this query CONCAT_WS(' ',recipient.fname, recipient.mname, recipient.lname) AS recipient_name might not be found (if there is no matched row in users table). Will this give any error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> CONCAT_WS() does not skip empty strings. However, it does skip any NULL values after the separator argument.

That should answer your question.

Comment: One more question, in this query CONCAT_WS(' ',recipient.fname, recipient.mname, recipient.lname) AS recipient_name might not be found (if there is no matched row in users table). Will this give any error?

Comment: If there are not matched rows, the function won't be called. Simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `CONCAT_WS` like that. If one of the arguments is NULL, there will be no error. The NULL argument is just not used.

It says this in the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws):

> CONCAT_WS() does not skip empty strings. However, it does skip any NULL values after the separator argument.

It's also very easy to verify this for yourself:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', 'abc', NULL, 'def')
'abc def'
```

Comment: One more question, in this query CONCAT_WS(' ',recipient.fname, recipient.mname, recipient.lname) AS recipient_name might not be found (if there is no matched row in users table). Will this give any error?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. If there will be `null` there wouldn't be any errors

Comment: is there any way to prevent  this extra space?

Comment: I corrected my answer seconds before your comment, extra space will be if one of them will be just empty. If it's null they are skipped.

Comment: So `SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ','sth','sth',null,'sth',null)` will return `sth sth sth` but `SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ','sth','sth','','sth','')` will return `sth sth  sth ` I don't think there is way to prevent extra space in second example

Comment: One more question, in this query CONCAT_WS(' ',recipient.fname, recipient.mname, recipient.lname) AS recipient_name might not be found (if there is no matched row in users table). Will this give any error?

Comment: It shouldn't. You should just get empty result for that `CONCAT_WS`

Comment: One more thing. You should correct your query, there are some extra `,`. One after second left join and after `AS recipient_name,` - that will throw some errors.

Answer (score 0):

Even though verbose, you need to use the COALESCE function when dealing with the potential for unacceptable NULL values:

```
CONCAT_WS(' ', COALESCE(val1, ''), COALESCE(val2, ''), ...)
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce

Comment: One more question, in this query CONCAT_WS(' ',recipient.fname, recipient.mname, recipient.lname) AS recipient_name might not be found (if there is no matched row in users table). Will this give any error?